# Xcode iPhone SDK (5.x) - CocoaLibSpotify iOS, Loading and Viewing playlists

Tags: spotify

iOS Spotify API.

I read the [documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/docs/11.1.60/browse_8c-example.html) on the `browse.m` example which seems to contain what i am looking for.

But i really don't know how to use it.

When the list of the playlists is called how do i display it in a `UITableView` ?

If i could joust get started i can probably figure out and accomplish what i want.

So basically i need a "kickstart" help code, and i'll be on my way (Figure of speech).

( Btw, yes i have the AppKey.c needed and i successfully #imported the API)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the sample projects included with CocoaLibSpotify for a general idea on how to interact with the library.

As for displaying playlists, well, playlists are stored in an `NSArray` and each have a `name` property, etc, so you'd put them into a table view just like you would any other list of data in the iOS SDK.